# How can I compute the difference between two images

Tags: wpf, image-processing

In my WPF project, I'd like to display the difference between two images.

If the two images are identical, the result would be a transparent image.
If they are different, it would be a pixel by pixel difference.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613146/computing-the-difference-between-images

Comment: What do you mean by pixel-by-pixel difference? Euclidean distance of the RGB values or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly then

```
r,g,b=abs(r1-r2),abs(g1-g2),abs(b1-b2)
```

is this what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the techniques used by webcam "security" apps for motion detection: eg [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Motion_Detection.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1) First convert both the images to binary image format [Black and White].
2) Compare the pixel value of both images. If, they differ. Note the position in separate collection. [Note: Pixel by Pixel comparison may cause performance problem if those two images were too big]
3) Use Adorner to decorate those pixels in highlighting color you prefer.

HTH