# Android How to get fast difference between two bitmaps

Tags: android, image, performance, android-ndk, bitmapimage

I need to get difference between 2 Bitmap Images in Android as fast and as efficient as possible. How can I achieve that? The implementation can be either in Java or in C using NDK.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about Difference, then [follow this detailed guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613146/computing-the-difference-between-images). But if you're talking about distance, then good ol' a^2 + b^2 = c^2 will do.

Comment: @KeremKusmezer No problemo. Be sure to close this question as it's irrelevant now.